# Oracle xml error

Tags: xml, oracle

On Oracle 11gr2, I import an xml file in a table:

```
INSERT INTO MS386_XML_TEMPLATE
VALUES (SYSDATE, pvNomeFile,
xmltype(bfilename(myDirectory, pvNomeFile), nls_charset_id('UTF8')));
```

When I select on this table, I have the following error:

```
SELECT TBELENCOPOD.POD
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  XMLCast(TBPOD.COLUMN_VALUE AS VARCHAR2(20)) AS POD
 FROM table(
       XMLSequence(
       XMLTYPE(Cursor(SELECT * FROM     MS386_XML_TEMPLATE)).extract('/ROWSET/ROW/XML_FILE/edi_l/trader/idrif     idrich/hdr/pod')
     )
    ) TBPOD) TBELENCOPOD LEFT JOIN MS038_METERS TBPOD ON
    TBELENCOPOD.POD=TBPOD.POD
    WHERE
     TBPOD.POD IS NULL
GROUP BY
 TBELENCOPOD.POD;

ORA-31011: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing 
LPX-00204: syntax error
Error at line 7
ORA-06512: a "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 343
ORA-06512: a line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

The xml is valid, I had checked it with a validator.
Thank you very much,
Igor
@Bob Jarvis thanks; here some lines of file:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_ReportFatturato_CONNESSIONE_02_2013.dtd">
<edi_l>
   <trader cdisp="DP1901">
      <idrif idrich="1512543258">
         <hdr>
            <odn>915000591962</odn>
            <pod>IT001E08654958</pod>
            <presa>027292224</presa>
            <cf>MNNMHL78H67L669B</cf>
            <piva/>
            <tdoc>F</tdoc>
            <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
            <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
            <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
            <tcon>0000220</tcon>
            <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
         </hdr>
         <pos>
            <cau>52</cau>
            <scau>09</scau>
            <codiva>A4</codiva>
            <udm/>
            <qta>000000000.0</qta>
            <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
            <impp>000000027.59</impp>
         </pos>
      </idrif>
      <idrif idrich="1512540815">
....
```

@Boneist, @Alex Poole: thanks for your replies; I'm new to Oracle XML DB and I know I'm doing a lot or errors!
I paste an example of the xml file I'm processing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_AAA_02_2013.dtd">
<edi_l>
<trader cdisp="zzzzzzz">
<idrif idrich="1111111111">
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT111111111111</pod>
  <presa>027292224</presa>
  <cf>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</cf>
  <piva></piva>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
<pos>
  <cau>52</cau>
  <scau>09</scau>
  <codiva>A4</codiva>
  <udm></udm>
  <qta>000000000.0</qta>
  <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
  <impp>000000027.59</impp>
</pos>
</idrif>
<idrif idrich="2222222222">
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT222222222222</pod>
  <presa>027290063</presa>
  <cf>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</cf>
  <piva></piva>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
<pos>
  <cau>52</cau>
  <scau>09</scau>
  <codiva>A4</codiva>
  <udm></udm>
  <qta>000000000.0</qta>
  <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
  <impp>000000027.59</impp>
</pos>
</idrif>
</trader>
</edi_l>
```

I would like to take, if the "pod" doesn't exist in the db, all its data and create a new valid xml file (one for each pod not found). So, for example, suppose the pod IT111111111111 was not found; Oracle must generate the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_AAA_02_2013.dtd">
<edi_l>
<trader cdisp="zzzzzzz">
<idrif idrich="1111111111">
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT111111111111</pod>
  <presa>027292224</presa>
  <cf>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</cf>
  <piva></piva>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
<pos>
  <cau>52</cau>
  <scau>09</scau>
  <codiva>A4</codiva>
  <udm></udm>
  <qta>000000000.0</qta>
  <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
  <impp>000000027.59</impp>
</pos>
</idrif>
</trader>
</edi_l>
```

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Please edit your question and include the first 15 lines of the XML file. Thanks.

Comment: Could you suply a complete xml document which produces the output, along with the output you're expecting to return? I'm guessing XMLTABLE() will be a part of the solution, but it's difficult to help without both bits of the information I requested.

Comment: What you've shown seems to work, aside from the spaces in your extract path, which get "LPX-00601: Invalid token" rather than a syntax error. The XML you're loading must be valid or you'd get an error on insert. As already mentioned, please post a minimal complete XML document that generates the error you see, and the actual extract path you're using. However, as extract and XMLSequence are deprecated, and you're doing this a complicated way. it does look like you should be using XMLTable; but without knowing quite what is causing the error you see, not sure if that is enough to avoid it.

Comment: Just for info, we don't get notifications if you mention us with @ in the question test, only in comments. I still don't get an error from the sample XML you added; on 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4; maybe you're on an earlier patch level? (Only other difference is that I don't have your DTD, so I'm removing that from the XML). Essentially you want to remove the `idrif` nodes whose `pod` values exist in the other table, right? What if a doc ends up with no nodes - leave an empty `trader` node, or don't have a doc at all?

Comment: @AlexPoole Alex thanks for your reply; yes you are right: I removed the line:
    <!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_ReportFatturato_CONNESSIONE_02_2013.dtd">
and no errors where generated; so how can I leave this line in the original file?
I execute the statement
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('alter session set events =''31156 trace name context forever, level 2''');
at the beginning of the Oracle package, but nothing seem to change.
Thanks, Igor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (also with the dtd in the original file --> special thanks to Marco Gralike):

```
select xt.pod    
from MS386_XML_TEMPLATE tab, xmltable ('/edi_l/trader/idrif/hdr'  
                      passing tab.XML_FILE    
                      columns    
                        pod VARCHAR2(20) path 'pod')  xt;
```

But why, if from the file I remove the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_ReportFatturato_CONNESSIONE_02_2013.dtd">
```

I have no errors?

At the beginning of the Oracle package, I run:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('alter session set events =''31156 trace name context     forever, level 2''');
```

to ignore the dtd: in this way, the loading of the file in the table works, but not the original query:

```
SELECT TBELENCOPOD.POD
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  XMLCast(TBPOD.COLUMN_VALUE AS VARCHAR2(20)) AS POD
 FROM table(
       XMLSequence(
       XMLTYPE(Cursor(SELECT * FROM     MS386_XML_TEMPLATE)).extract('/ROWSET/ROW/XML_FILE/edi_l/trader/idrif     idrich/hdr/pod')
     )
    ) TBPOD) TBELENCOPOD LEFT JOIN MS038_METERS TBPOD ON
    TBELENCOPOD.POD=TBPOD.POD
    WHERE
     TBPOD.POD IS NULL
GROUP BY
 TBELENCOPOD.POD;
```

Thanks,
Igor